# JQuery function created inside a user control inside a repeater inside an update panel is not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

When I move my user control outside of the repeater and (still inside the update panel) pass its properties manually instead of using repeater, everything works fine. But when I use the repeater to pass properties to my user control, the user control gets loaded from database fine and appears on the final client page which shows those parameters (PID, StID) passes successfully but its jQuery function stops working. So again jQuery works fine outside of the repeater.

Things I tried:

1. Since they say repeater messes up with the unique ID of the elements, I used class instead. This did not work. I also used unique IDs for class and element ID's, which didn't work either. Now I am using unique names for classes inside repeater because my PID is a GUID and I construct unique stuff there for class names.
2. Moved myusercontrol out of repeater. This works.
3. I created another page and I manually give properties to my user control. This works fine.
4. I wrote one similar script to what u see in the post but outside of the repeater to simply hide and show my  element inside the user control within the repeater. but that also did not work! I cannot even see the html output of the user control in the final page>view source ( I guess MS uses different mechanism to hide them ) although I see user control on the final page! unless I put the user control outside the repeater or I use chrome dev tool then I can see the html output of user control. I am not sure if it has something to do with this.

MyPage.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="49px" Style="margin-left: 211px">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSrc1" ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <div id='FC<%# Eval("PID")%><%# Eval("SID")%>'>
                                    <UserControl:MView runat="Server" PelID='<%#Eval("PID")%>' StID='<%#Eval("SID") %>' ID="Mview1" ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="False" />                            
                                </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSrc1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT PID, SID FROM [fc] LEFT JOIN [pt] ON [pt].ID = [fc].PID WHERE ([pt].[TID] = @TID)">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TreeView1" Name="TID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" DefaultValue="5AF4D771-9DA9-46B9-8075-200DF8652063" Type="String" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>  
           </ContentTemplate>    
            </asp:UpdatePanel>           
        </asp:Panel>
```

User.Ascx

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("body").on( 'click', "#front<%= PID.ToString()%><%=StID.ToString()%>",function (e) {
           alert('test');
           $("div.divBC<%= PID.ToString()%><%=StID.ToString()%>").hide();
            $("div.divCF<%= PID.ToString()%><%=StID.ToString()%>").show();
           e.preventDefault();
           e.disablePopup();
           return false;

        });

        $("body").on('click', "#back<%= PID.ToString()%><%=StID.ToString()%>", function (e) {
            alert("before Back");
            $("div.divCF<%= PID.ToString()%><%=StID.ToString()%>").hide();
            $("div.divBC<%= PID.ToString()%><%=StID.ToString()%>").css('visibility', 'visible');
            $("div.divBC<%= PID.ToString()%><%=StID.ToString()%>").show();
            e.preventDefault();
            e.disablePopup();
            return false;
        });
    });


</script>
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Lable1" runat="server" Text="--"></asp:Label></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="--"></asp:Label></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="--"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" >
                <hr style="color: #C0C0C0" />
                <span>
                    Time: 
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="SpecialTime"></asp:Literal>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    Last Time : [under construction! ]
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="OtherThings"></asp:Literal>
                </span>
                <hr />
                <div class="divCF<%= PID.ToString()%><%=StID.ToString()%>">
                    <hr/>
                    <h3>
                        <span>                            
                            <br />
                            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Title"></asp:Literal>
                        </span>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="divBC<%= PID.ToString()%><%=StID.ToString()%>" style="visibility:hidden">                    
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="TextCnt"></asp:Literal>
                    <input type="hidden" value="<%= PID.ToString() %>" id="PDHolder"/>
                    <input type="hidden" value="<%= StID.ToString() %>" id="StIDHolder"/>
                    <hr/>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;           
                <button id="front<%= PID.ToString()%><%=StID.ToString()%>">Front</button>
                <button id="back<%= PID.ToString()%><%=StID.ToString()%>">Back</button> 
            </center>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Your **Usercontrol** code will be repeated **N** times since it's in a repeater and so does the script inside the usercontrol. Better remove those script and place it either on parent page or master page in _End of Body_ section.

Comment: I can improve on that later maybe, but is that the answer to the problem I posted?

Comment: beside my aim is to hide and show some div elements inside each individual user control. So I am fully aware that the script gets repeated and I even give it unique IDs. If as you say I have one script in master page it will hide and show all the dive elements of my all user controls in same time  together unless you are suggesting some JQuery solution that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Repeated

```
<button id="front">
```

and

```
$("body").on( 'click', "#front",function (e)
```

do not mix well.

Another thing. You must include jQuery javascript only once in a page.

Comment: why not? let's say I have many buttons who can raise a click event and that code will react to any event happening? Nevertheless based on your suggestion I gave both of them unique IDs and still works fine (hide and show) outside the repeater but not inside!

Comment: Because 1 - `id` attributes are to *uniquely* **id**entify html elements and should not be repeated on a given page, and 2 - selectors such as `"#front"` will return at most one element - the first one that is found by `id`.

Comment: well it does not even return that one element! anyway I tried and I gave them unique IDs as u suggested and it doesnt work inside repeater :(

Comment: I don't know what your code looks like now, so I have nothing to say.

Comment: I updated the code, that is how it looks like now and the problem persist

Comment: @Araz Please, note my edit about multiple inclusions of jquery.min.js.

Comment: I saw it and I removed that line out of repeating. I updated the code again still problem persist.